# What EXACTLY are the "outflow" and "pressure outlet" BCs in ANSYS Fluent?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, boundary-conditions, ansys-fluent

I am just starting my MSc and we have been given an assignment in which we must model two-dimensional, laminar, incompressible Poiseuille flow in a channel. We are supposed to use a VELOCITY INLET inlet boundary condition and two different outlet boundary conditions - the OUTFLOW boundary condition and the PRESSURE OUTLET boundary condition. The problem is I don't understand exactly what these boundary conditions are. I am dealing with a simple rectangular domain with four sides (Inlet, outlet, and top/bottom wall). The flow moves from left to right. I will make a list below showing which boundary conditions I know and which I do not know.

**VELOCITY**

- Inlet : Dirichlet, $\boldsymbol u=\boldsymbol u_{\text{inlet}}$
- Outlet : **???**
- Top and Bottom Wall : Dirichlet, $\boldsymbol u=0$

**PRESSURE**

- Inlet : **???**
- Outlet : **???**
- Top and Bottom Wall : Neumann, $\boldsymbol n\cdot\nabla p=0$

As you can see, I am unsure of the outlet conditions on $\boldsymbol u$, and the inlet AND outlet conditions on $p$. I don't know what these are when Fluent is using the OUTFLOW and PRESSURE OUTLET conditions. I had a look at [this thread on CFD online](https://www.cfd-online.com/Forums/fluent/41670-difference-between-pressure-outlet-outflow.html), but it still isn't clear exactly what BCs Fluent is using. And the ANSYS official documentation is absolutely abysmal as well.

As I understand from the linked thread, the OUTFLOW condition assumes a Neumann condition on all flow variables *except* the pressure. So, what does it do with the pressure?!

And, it seems that the PRESSURE OUTLET boundary condition assumes a Dirichlet condition on the pressure. But what does it do with the velocity?!

Finally, in both of these cases, what boundary condition is the VELOCITY INLET choice assigning for the pressure at the inlet?

Would really appreciate some clarity here whatever rigorous mathematical language is needed to express it.

I asked this question on CFD Online but got no responses.

Comment: You can generally only prescribe either the velocity of the traction (of which the pressure is a part). You can't prescribe both at the same time.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth So, if I understand you correctly, there is no inlet condition on the pressure?? This really defies my intuition. But, parking that, what conditions are being used at the outlet?

Comment: Like I said, if you prescribe the velocity, then the pressure is what it is: you can't separately say "oh, *and* the pressure should also be this or that". And if you prescribe the traction, then you can't *also* say what the velocity should be.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth But if you have a look at the backwards facing step tutorial case in OpenFOAM (which is called "pitzDaily" in the folder) there is a Neumann condition at the inlet AND a Dirichlet condition at the outlet for the pressure

Comment: Right -- you can have one kind of boundary condition on one part of the boundary, and another kind of boundary condition on another part of the boundary. You just can't prescribe *both* kinds on the same part of the boundary.